# Class Card won't convert to String

Tags: java

I am working on a basic poker application. The Card and DeckOfCards classes seem to work fine in most cases, but when I try to deal the community cards (board cards), I get a compiler error. I'm a little perplexed since it seems I'm doing the same exact thing in the previous for loop when dealing the player's hands.

card.java:

```
public class Card {
    private final String face;
    private final String suit;

    public Card(String cardFace, String cardSuit) {
        this.face = cardFace;
        this.suit = cardSuit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return face + suit;
    }
}
```

DeckOfCards.java:

```
public class DeckOfCards {

    private static final SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52;

    private Card[] deck = new Card[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
    private int currentCard = 0;

    public DeckOfCards() {
        String[] faces = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K"};
        String[] suits = {"h", "c", "d", "s"};

        for(int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++) {
            deck[count] = new Card(faces[count % 13], suits[count/13]);
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        currentCard = 0;

        for (int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++) {
            int second = randomNumbers.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_CARDS);

            Card temp = deck[first];
            deck[first] = deck[second];
            deck[second] = temp;
        }
    }

    public Card dealCard() {
        if (currentCard < deck.length) {
            return deck[currentCard++];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

DeckOfCardsTest.java:

```
public class DeckOfCardsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeckOfCards myDeckOfCards = new DeckOfCards();
        myDeckOfCards.shuffle();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Enter number of players(max 10): ");
        int numPlayers = input.nextInt();

        if(numPlayers > 10)
            numPlayers = 10;

        String[] playerHand = new String[10];
        String[] boardCards = new String[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            playerHand[i] = myDeckOfCards.dealCard() + " " + myDeckOfCards.dealCard();
            System.out.printf("Player %d Hand: %s%n", (i + 1), playerHand[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            boardCards[i] = myDeckOfCards.dealCard();
                        //^This is the line that throws the error

        }

        System.out.printf("Flop: %s %s %s%n", boardCards[0], boardCards[1], boardCards[2]);
        System.out.printf("Turn: %s%n", boardCards[3]);
        System.out.printf("River: %s%n", boardCards[4]);



    }
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
DeckOfCardsTest.java:25: error: incompatible types: Card cannot be converted to String
boardCards[i] = myDeckOfCards.dealCard();
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first for loop you are doing `myDeckOfCards.dealCard() + " " + myDeckOfCards.dealCard()`, the use of `+ " "` converts the `Card` class returned by `dealCard` to String.

So to fix your problem you can do `dealCard().toString()` or `dealCard() + ""`

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense now; I was aware of implicit and explicit conversions in theory, but now I understand in practice.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception states, in line 25 of your DeckOfCardsTest code, you're assigning the result of dealCard() method, which is of type Card, to an element of boardCards array which is of type String. Java does not implicitly convert custom classes to string.
You could change type of boardCards from String[] to Card[].
or you can do:

```
boardCards[i] = myDeckOfCards.dealCard().toSring();
```

Answer (score 0):

`myDeckOfCards.dealCard()` return a `Card` object, not a `String` and you cannot directly convert a `Card` object to a `String`.  It looks like you want to declare your arrays as `Card` arrays, not `String` arrays.

```
Card[] playerHand = new Card[10];
Card[] boardCards = new Card[5];
```

If you really want a `String`, call `toString()` on the `Card` object.  There is an implicit `toString()` call when concatenating an object to a String, but not on direct assignment.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                playerHand[i] = myDeckOfCards.dealCard() + " " + myDeckOfCards.dealCard();
                System.out.printf("Player %d Hand: %s%n", (i + 1), playerHand[i]);
            }

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    boardCards[i] = myDeckOfCards.dealCard().toString();  //need to explicitly call toString() here.
    //^This is the line that throws the error

            }
```

See this test code below will fail to compile for the same reason.  The first line is OK, but the second one isn't because it's a direct assignment, not a concatenation.

```
public class Test { 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String test="blah" + new Integer(7); //this is OK.  Implicit toString() call
      String test2=new Integer(7); //compile error here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I only be able to store one card (i.e. 2h or 6d) in each member of the array if I declare them as type Card, rather than the entire two-card hand?

Comment: @TheoK Yes, that is correct.  I did not notice that when I made my comment that you were storing two cards in one element.  In that case, you would have to make either  a two dimensional array or use a Tuple of some sort to wrap a pair of cards.

Answer (score 0):

using the .toString() method you can convert it to string type and everything will be okay.
Use this at the error line.

```
boardCards[i] = myDeckOfCards.dealCard().toSring();
```